# What does the Bind bindkeys-file directive do?

Tags: dns, bind, dnssec

Just trying to understand the `bindkeys-file` directive related to the DNSSEC extension in the Bind configuration. Is that a public key? Does it sign the response in the same way as digital signatures?

Comment: Please do not use code markup to highlight words, only for code. You don't need to highlight words in every sentence.

Answer (score 7):

It’s actually an alternative repository for trusted keys, where one can submit their zone keys, if there is no fully signed path from root zone down to your own zone. The functional DLV registry is `dlv.isc.org`. By default the root zone key and the `dlv.isc.org` key are included in `/etc/named.iscdlv.key` and that goes as a value to `bindkeys-file` attribute in Options directive.  you can find this automatically in `named.conf` or `named.options`.

from `/usr/share/doc/bind-9.7.3/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf`:

`bindkeys-file` The pathname of a file to override the built-in trusted keys provided by named. See the discussion of dnssec-lookaside and dnssec-validation for details. If not specified, the default is /etc/bind.keys.

Comment: I will read that `PDF` later, answer upvoted